# Lightweight Generics and class methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, generics

I have a Core Data category method on `NSManagedObject` that returns an array of objects matching a predicate:

```
  + (NSArray *)objectsWhere:(NSPredicate *)predicate
```

I'd like the return type to be annotated so that I don't have to perform a cast in Swift.

**E.g, I'd like to say:**

```
    let modelArray = Model.objectsWhere(predicate)
    // Do stuff to an array of Models.
```

**Instead of**

```
if let modelArray = Model.objectsWhere(predicate) as? [Model] {
   // Do stuff to an array of models.
}
```

Is this possible? And if so, how does one do it? I've tried:

```
 + (NSArray<id>)objectsWhere:(NSPredicate* _Nonnull)predicate

 + (NSArray<NSManagedObject *>)objectsWhere:(NSPredicate* _Nonnull)predicate

 + (NSArray<__kindof NSManagedObject *>)objectsWhere:(NSPredicate* _Nonnull)predicate
```

And they all insist that I cast the result to `[Model]`. `id` wasn't a surprise, but I was really hoping that the `__kindof` bit would work, since all models are a kind of `NSManagedObject`, but no.

Comment: What were the return types in swift for those 3 signatures that you tried?

Comment: `Model` is a base class to all of your model classes? However, `NSManagedObject` isn't `Model`. Show the Swift code.

Comment: did you happen to find a solution to your problem? Because i'm in the same position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't do it, which is kind of a bummer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `__kindof` is only used in Objective-C, and there is no similar construct for Swift types.